# I want to prove that for all normal number (M ) Takes place of GCD(m!+1,(m+1)!+1)=1 is true

Tags: solution-verification

I want to prove that for all normal number (M ) Takes place of
(m!+1,(m+1)!+1)=1 is true

Comment: What does "Takes place of (m!+1,(m+1)!+1)=1 is true" mean?

Comment: it mean that GCD for (m!+1,(m+1)!+1)=1 is true for any M we try

Comment: For that matter, what do you mean by "normal number"?  [normal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number) have a precise definition, but I doubt you have that definition in mind.

Comment: i mean M>0 so if we try to use 1 or 2 we always will get the answer of GCD equal to 1

Comment: So I think you just mean "natural number".  Anyway, I have posted something below.  I think it is relevant, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (but am not sure) that you are asking:  for $n\in \mathbb N$ show that $\gcd(n!+1,(n+1)!+1)=1$

To see that, suppose we had a counterexample $n$. Then let $p$ be a prime which divided $\gcd(n!+1,(n+1)!+1)$.  It would then follow that $p$ divided the difference $(n+1)!+1-n!-1=(n+1)!-n!=n!\times n$.  But if $p\,|\,n!\times n$ then $p\,|\,n!$ in which case we certainly have $p\,\nmid (n!+1)$ so we have a contradiction, and we are done.

Comment: yea that true , thx very much